# Difference between "Oracle Siebel CRM On Demand" and salesforce.com CRM

Tags: crm, salesforce, siebel, ondemand

Looking for differences between Oracle's Siebel CRM On Demand and salesforce.com CRM

Actually looking for points favouring the Siebel OD CRM

Tried googling and bing-ing it but found old stale information from around 3-4 yrs back, so any links to updated information will also be appreciated deeply.

And while we are on the subject, how good are the prospects of a career in Siebel On Demand CRM.

Thanks for your time people.

Comment: Er... this is a programming site for asking programming questions, not subjective sales-related questions...

Comment: I think its valid because
1. He is asking for differences, not a subjective (which is better) answer.
2. He is asking for technical differences, not price plans!!
3. The last section about the career is accepted in SO also

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Having developed in Siebel for over 13 years, Siebel/Oracle CRM OnDemand for 3-4 years and SFDC for 6-7 months. You made the right decision. Oracle CRM OnDemand is a useless piece of junk. If it can't solve your business requirements OOTB it basically never will. It has absolutely no server side code support and the client side JavaScript is limited to only 1500 characters. You can however include your own javascript files but you will need to host them on another server, which kind of beats the purpose of using Oracle's hosted environment in the first place.

If you are using Oracle CRM OnDemand I here from good inside sources that there is no upgrade path for any custom configurations at all to the planned Fusion CRM platform. Apparently your data will be migrated but no configurations.

Now I don't believe that SFDC is the greatest thing that I have ever seen, but in comparrison to Oracle CRM Ondmand they are not even in the same game. Do yourself a favour and switch to SFCD, if you haven't purchaed Oracle CRM OnDemand, seriously don't waste your time.

Comment: +1 I can attest to the garbage that is CRM on demand. Avoid it like the plague.

Answer (score 1):

We could not find anything that favored Siebel and consequently switched to Salesforce.

Never been happier.